# Is it possible to connect multiple projects to Firebase Local Emulator Suite? Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

is this possible since the Local Emulator Suite is configured and installed on the directory of of just one project?  I have a 2 apps that I need to see the effects over the other.